# How to enter multiple rows in mySQL from form data where one field changes

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a form which asks some basic questions about a job, and then asks to person entering to list all those colleagues that were with them at the time. What I want to do is for all colleagues present to have a row entered in to the database - so all the other details remain the same except for their work_id (which is the identifier for the person). My code below seems to submit 1 row to the db with the workID field empty

```
<?php
require_once('includes/dbconnect.php');

$varWorkID = $_POST['workid'];
$varDate = $_POST['date'];
$varType = $_POST['type'];
$varSuper = $_POST['supervisor'];
$varReference = $_POST['reference'];

//Remove last part of array as extra 1 sent through by form 
$workID = array_pop($varWorkID);

for ($i=0; $i < count($workID); $i++ )
{
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO searches (workid,date,type,super,reference) VALUES('".$workID."','".$varDate."','".$varType."','".$varSuper."','".$varReference."')");
}
echo "Completed";
```

I think I'm fairly close but I just need to get workid  to be populated with each of the Work IDs for each of the employees present.

Any assistance greatly appreciated

Comment: This code is extremely vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider using prepared statements.

Comment: Do `var_dump($varWorkID);` and see what you're getting.

Comment: `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "AB123" [1]=> string(5) "CD456" [2]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: You need change loop definition `for ($i=0; $i < count($varWorkID); $i++ )` and swap `$workID` for `$varWorkID[$i]` in SQL string

Comment: Thanks Dima. Jeff credited you below too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is that you're calling `$workID = array_pop($varWorkID);` before you go into the loop `for ($i=0; $i < count($workID); $i++ )`, so the PHP interpreter thinks you just want to iterate over the length of that one element. what you actually wanted to do was pop an element off the array *while inside* the loop.

```
<?php
require_once('includes/dbconnect.php');

$varWorkID = $_POST['workid'];
$varDate = $_POST['date'];
$varType = $_POST['type'];
$varSuper = $_POST['supervisor'];
$varReference = $_POST['reference'];


// iterate over the count of the whole array $varWorkID = $_POST['workid']
for ($i=0; $i < count($varWorkID); $i++ )
{
    // now pop off the array inside the loop
    //Remove last part of array as extra 1 sent through by form 
    $workID = array_pop($varWorkID);
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO searches (workid,date,type,super,reference) VALUES('".$workID."','".$varDate."','".$varType."','".$varSuper."','".$varReference."')");
}
echo "Completed";
```

now I think [@Dima Fitiskin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959993/how-to-enter-multiple-rows-in-mysql-from-form-data-where-one-field-changes#comment-61479221) proposes a better approach because you don't really need the expense of calling another function `array_pop` or throwing another variable on the stack `$workID` when you've already got an iterated reference to the index `$i` inside the loop.

```
<?php
require_once('includes/dbconnect.php');

$varWorkID = $_POST['workid'];
$varDate = $_POST['date'];
$varType = $_POST['type'];
$varSuper = $_POST['supervisor'];
$varReference = $_POST['reference'];


// iterate over the count of the whole array $varWorkID = $_POST['workid']
for ($i=0; $i < count($varWorkID); $i++ )
{
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO searches (workid,date,type,super,reference) VALUES('".$varWorkID[$i]."','".$varDate."','".$varType."','".$varSuper."','".$varReference."')");
}
echo "Completed";
```